# Windows Azure Web sites python

Tags: python, azure, flask, pymongo, azure-web-app-service

After a whole load of hard work I've eventually got a hello world flask app running on Windows Azure, the app is built locally and runs fine, deploying it to Azure is a nightmare though. So I've sort of got two questions here.

I can't seem to get a stack trace at all, I've tried setting things in web.config, but the documentation on how to use all this stuff is just apawling, all I can find is just literally badly written blog posts dotted around one of microsoft's millions of blogs. Which doesn't even help me to fix my problem.

The second question relates to the first one, due to some horrible debugging methods (taking my application apart and commenting things out) I feel like it could be pymongo causing this, I've built it without the C extensions and it's in my site-packages and it works on my local machine. However without a stack trace I've just no idea how to fix this without wanting to pull my hair out.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Really disappointing because the rest of azure isn't too bad, theres far better website hosting alternatives out there like heroku which are literally 10 command setups. I've been working on this all day so far..

Comment: For those who are running into similar issues and come here for more info - we are working on supporting Flask and Bottle web apps with one-click deploy to Azure (and providing enough infrastructure for you to easily wire up any other framework) in PTVS 2.1. The current dev builds already include this functionality. The included web.config can also be used as a template for your own custom deployment.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

For those who are interested I ended up solving this problem my manually adding error handling into my flask application completely bypassing the IIS settings and windows azure configs - far too complicated with no documentation at all.

```
from werkzeug.debug import get_current_traceback   

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(e):
    base = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    f = open('%s/logs/error.log' % (base), 'a')
    track = get_current_traceback(skip=1, show_hidden_frames=True, ignore_system_exceptions=False)
    track.log(f)
    f.close()

    return 'An error has occured', 500
```