# Flask app doesn't builds on MS Azure cloud

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I want to deploy my flask web application on Azure cloud. In Deployment options, I have selected GitHub as source destination for my flask code. after doing the configuration test successfully, the init.py file now starts building;[image]

Now when I go to my application link, it shows me this;[image]

Now at this point, I went back to my deployment options, it says Building failed;
[image]

the log generated for this building failed can be seen in the first picture. All the tests has passed except the last one "Performance test". Have anyone encountered the same issue before ? what can be the reason for that ?

I am running the application on localhost @ port 8000.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
  return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

Do I need to run it on another IP ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot listen on port 8000 in Web Apps. Only port 80 or 443. You'll need to read the port number from the environment, to know what to listen on.

Comment: Changed the port number to 80 now. Now I get "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." ...  I can see that in deployment option, is still loading on building. How much time should it take to build for such a tiny app? It's taking too long

Comment: Deployment is active now,  but still getting same error  "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.". M running it on local host at port 80. From which environment do we need to read  the port number?

Comment: You should really use logs to get to the root cause. There's a project Kudu thing in azure, which you should use to get the logs and other valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `500` error, I think some python packages are not installed correctly.

To check your code is working correctly in naive manner, do as follows.

1. If you are developing on Windows machine, copy all of your `site-packages` files in development machine to WebApp `/site/wwwroot/env/Lib/site-packages` folder.
2. Hit `Restart` in Azure Portal and `F5` in browser.

If it works, your deployment process might have a problem. Mainly it is caused by library installation.

First, check you have `requirements.txt` at the root folder. [This documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/#git-publishing) describes some considerations to load Flask on Azure WebApp. Of course, it would be *really* helpful to read the documentation from the first line carefully.

Second, login WebApp via FTP and check the package is installed correctly. You can see `/pip` folder has `pip.log` file, and `/site/wwwroot/env/Lib/site-packages` folder has its libraries.

For some libraries which you might require more than simple hello world app, you may have to push x86 `.whl` files along with python codes as they are not installed correctly in x86 environment.

Additionally, in order to show internal error to outside, consider to apply [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174092/361100) during development (not for production).

Answer (score 0):

If you created the Azure Webapp using the Flask tool, the default app is called `FlaskWebProject1`. If your app has a different name, you need to modify `web.config` in your `wwwroot` folder to reflect the correct app name.

Then redeploy using the Azure portal or change it in your GIT and push again.